# Not able to interact with Web Based Terminal through Selenium

Tags: web, terminal

My problem statement is related to interacting with a web based terminal 
    through selenium

- I logged into one site.
- I clicked on specific Jupyter application
- I selected terminal in the Jupyter application
- I have landed on a blank black screen where I need to pass the below 
      command and get the access token.

Command

```
curl -X POST https://dummyterminal/oauth/token -k -H 
'authorization: Basic Authcode'  -H 'content-type: application/x-www- 
 form-urlencoded'  -d 
 'username=username&password=#password&grant_type=password'
```

I tried to capture the whole flow from Selenium IDE also, in order to  find out if terminal has some web element or not
For terminal it is showing the web element as 
`cssSelector("canvas.xterm-cursor-layer")` through Selenium IDE, but when I ran with same web element it has thrown below error

I tried searching on Google also but most of the solutions were related       interaction of putty with Java code means interaction of desktop 
application which is putty with Java code but in my case I need 
interaction with web based terminal(which is kind of putty) with selenium 
so that I can paste my commands there and retrieve the output

I am not able to paste the above command in the web based terminal, 
getting below error:-

output:-

```
    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element
              (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.77)
              (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
            Command duration or timeout: 70 milliseconds
            Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: 'XXXX', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
            System info: host: 'XXXX', ip: 'XXXXXX', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
            Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
            Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.36.540470 (e522d04694cxxxx7e21272dbef4f9b818c91), userDataDir=C:\Users\XXXXX[enter image description here][1]\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir3736_24657}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=70.0.3538.77, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
            Session ID: f629216f0f8cvvvvvv6f7d95
                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
                at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
                at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
                at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
                at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:327)
                at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:122)
                at getToken.getAccessToken.captureTerminalOutput(getAccessToken.java:52)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
                at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
                at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
                at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
                at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
                at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
                at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
                at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
                at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
                at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
                at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
                at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
                at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
                at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
                at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
                at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
                at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
                at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
                at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
                at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)


            ===============================================
                Default test
                Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
            ===============================================


            ===============================================
            Default suite
            Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
            ===============================================
```